# How do I enable UPnP support in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, router, port-forwarding, upnp

Is there a checklist for enabling UPnP in Windows 7?

I am on a home network with Network Discovery enabled in Network and Sharing Center, UPnP is enabled on my router, `SSDP Discovery` and `UPnP Device Host` services are also running, but I still cannot open a port through UPnP.

Additionally, is there a tool which I could use to check it it works?

Comment: What program are you trying to open the ports with?

Comment: Actually, it's a custom C# app based on [this article](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP.aspx). (I've also tried with [UPnP Test Tool by Mark Gillespie](http://www.junegillespie.plus.com/UPnPTest.exe) and it didn't work either).

Comment: Have you checked the firewall?

Comment: @Peter: I am not sure what to check? There are no fixed forwarding rules; apps should be able to add port mappings directly to the router. This is the part where they fail to detect the router as an UPnP device. Also, if I got it right, router should show up under network in Windows Explorer if it is "discoverable", and this does not happen.

Comment: The quickest way to test to see if it's the firewall, would be to turn it off then test your program. If it works then it's a firewall setting, and if it doesn't then it's something else.

Comment: @Peter: Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: Do you have another router that you know that works with UPnP you can test it with?  Do you have this problem with all devices in your network?  You tried doing a hard reset of the router?  Lastly, if you have a flashable router, have you tried something like DD-WRT to see if it's not a router firmware issue?  I know the last two alternatives are rather extreme, but I'm just offering suggestions you can use.

Answer (score -1):

UPnP is a protocol to allow devices to traverse through NAT as well.
  So more importantly, make sure your Router supports UPnP.

Comment: As I wrote, UPnP is enabled on my router. Since `[x] Enable UPnP` is checked in the routers web admin interface, I am pretty sure it's supported.